# How to avoid 'ConvertFrom-Csv | ConvertTo-Json' creating an array (square brackets)

Tags: powershell

I have a very simple script which is designed to convert a csv-file into a json-file, as this is required for me to transport the file via certain middleware. When converting from csv to json using below code, it automatically adds square brackets around the output (which I believe means it converted it as an array):

```
$TestFile = 'E:\TestFile.prn'

if(Test-Path $TestFile) {
    (Get-Content $TestFile| ConvertFrom-Csv) | ConvertTo-Json -compress | Out-File "E:\TestFile.json"
}
```

This does everything what I would expect it to do, except that it adds square brackets around the resulting output. I want the exact same output, but without the square brackets. Is there a way to do it during the above conversion, or is there a way to add an extra command line which removes the brackets?

Many thanks in advance!

Best regards

Comment: An example of the content of your csv file?

Comment: It adds square brackets because it's describing a collection. Does the CSV file only contain 1 row, or...?

Comment: Example content would be this:

"TESTCOLUMN1","TESTCOLUMN2","TESTCOLUMN3","TESTCOLUMN4"
"TestValue_1A","TestValue_2A","TestValue_3A","TestValue_4A"
"TestValue_1B","TestValue_2B","TestValue_3B","TestValue_4B"

Indeed as soon as it contains more than one row, it adds the square brackets. Resulting output looks like this once it's more than one row:

[{"TESTCOLUMN1":"TestValue_1A","TESTCOLUMN2":"TestValue_2A","TESTCOLUMN3":"TestValue_3A","TESTCOLUMN4":"TestValue_4A"},{"TESTCOLUMN1":"TestValue_1B","TESTCOLUMN2":"TestValue_2B","TESTCOLUMN3":"TestValue_3B","TESTCOLUMN4":"TestValue_4B"}]

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the square brackets are correct JSON. It's returning an array because it's an array.

However, you can just remove the first and last characters of the string:

```
Import-Csv -Path $TestFile |
    ConvertTo-Json -Compress |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Substring(1, $_.Length - 2) } |
    Out-File "E:\TestFile.json"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does the trick! Very new to powershell so I appreciate the help. So just for my understanding, the reason it is technically an array is because it is a collection of JSON-objects, those objects being rows in my CSV-file?